# How to execute a job-submitting script for all the files with a specific (range of) pattern in linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, batch-file, slurm

I am doing some calculations on CentOS 7.7 on a supercomputing server. Let's say I have a folder "tmp_folder" containing the following files:

```
input1.traj, input2.traj, input3.traj, ..., input_5000.traj, random1.traj, random2.traj, ..., random1000.traj
```

Now I want to execute a SLURM job-submitting script for 74 files that have the filenames from "input_78" to "input_151". The script for submitting a single job (78) is as follow:

```
module load GPAW
gpaw sbatch -- --job-name=job_78 -e error_78.err -o output_78.out -n 16 -N 1 -p xeon16 -t 80:00:00 --mail-type=END,FAIL --mail-user=xxxxx@xxx.xx calc.py tmp_folder//input78.traj
```

where GPAW is just a computational tool to do the calculations, "calc.py" is the main Python script for running the calculation, the "inputxx.traj" file is the input trajectory file.

How could I execute this script for those specific 74 files? It's okay if someone doesn't know what SLURM is. Basically all I want to do is to constantly modify the job-submitting script, substituting the "78"s with "79", "80" and so on until "151". It is worth noting that I don't want to mess up the other part of the script, *e.g.* the walltime and the number of nodes. I would prefer a Python script to do the trick if possible, but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below's some simple bash, using a sequence from 78 to 151 in for loop

```
for i in {78..151} 
do
   module load GPAW
   gpaw sbatch -- --job-name=job_$i -e error_$i.err -o output_$i.out -n 16 -N 1 -p xeon16 -t 80:00:00 --mail-type=END,FAIL --mail-user=xxxxx@xxx.xx calc.py tmp_folder//input$i.traj
done
```